# Esp32 Camera module: A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm trying to program a ESP32 Camera module with the Arduino IDE (I also tried with Platform IO. I'm  programming the ESP32 Camera via a FDTI Programmer on 5V. The project I'm trying to load is the CameraWebServer example file. The wiring is good, I have GPIO0 connected to GND. The FDTI Programmer's outputs 5V (I checked with a multimeter). I have the FDTI drivers installed and my Windows detects it as a FDTI COM port. But I still get this same error message, after all this:

Connecting........_____....._
A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header

I get this following output:

```
Sketch uses 2594774 bytes (82%) of program storage space. Maximum is 3145728 bytes.
Global variables use 56256 bytes (17%) of dynamic memory, leaving 271424 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
esptool.py v3.0-dev
Serial port COM6
Connecting........_____....._
Chip is ESP32-D0WDQ6 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 91:b2:7e:e4:fe:8c
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Warning: Could not auto-detect Flash size (FlashID=0x0, SizeID=0x0), defaulting to 4MB
Compressed 8192 bytes to 47...
Writing at 0x0000e000... (100 %)
Wrote 8192 bytes (47 compressed) at 0x0000e000 in 0.0 seconds (effective 2048.0 kbit/s)...

A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

EDIT

When I click on the **rst** button on the board, I get this error:

```
A fatal error occurred: Invalid head of packet (0x65)
```

Comment: Make sure the FTDI adapter can deliver enough current, or use a different  (external) power supply. The ESP32 outputs 3.3V signals from its serial port but the  FTDI adapter may expect (and output) 5V logic level signals. Many (most?) FTDI adapters can be switched from 5V to 3.3V.

Comment: I also tried that, but to no avail :(

Comment: I bought another ESP32 camera from amazon and it works. The one I was sold was garbage and wasted my time.